# Mongoose get updated document after instance.update()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am executing a mongoose `Model.findById()` function in order to return a single instance by utilizing an express route.

```
Model.findById(modelid)
        .then(instance => {
            if(instance.isOwnedBy(user)) {
                return instance.update({$push: {days: req.params.dayid}}, {new: true})
                               .then(foo => res.send(foo))
            } else {
                res.status(401).send("Unauthorized")
            }
        })
```

the above code returns an object containing the `opTime, electionId...etc` instead of returning the newly updated document instance. How am I able return the **newly updated document** after the `instance.update()` method?

Comment: @srinivasy it did in fact update the document

Comment: From the docs: Model.update() `Updates one document in the database without returning it.`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc even though I am calling it on a document instance and not the model? is there a function that does return the newly updated document?

Comment: maybe you can findOneAndUpdate() with same option {new:true} in order to return new document as update will only return write result !!

Comment: As you have additional condition here `instance.isOwnedBy(user)`, can it be converted to one mongoose query?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc the method checks if ‘req.user == trip.user’ I suppose we could try to ‘findOneAndUpdate()’ where _id is the Id and user: user. I would need to handle two error cases. One where the document isn’t found (404) & one where the user is not authorized (401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `instance.isOwnedBy(user)` and `_id: modelid` can be merged into one mongo query, it's better to use `findOneAndUpdate()` but in that way, if it doesn't find any document match, you can not know which part of the query causes the not found.

And because I don't know much about your models, conditions, I can not answer how to do it with `findOneAndUpdate()` but there is another way that modify the document and call `save()` method.

Example base on your code:

```
Model.findById(modelid)
    .then(instance => {
        if(instance && instance.isOwnedBy(user)) {
            if(instance.days) instance.days.push(req.params.dayid);
            else instance.days = [req.params.dayid];
            instance.save().then(function(instance){
              res.send(instance);
            })
        } else {
            res.status(401).send("Unauthorized")
        }
    })
```

Note: You should check if the instance exist or not before modify it.